# Azure Web App. IIS 10. Web Config. Running a static file with a ASP.NET Core app

Tags: asp.net, azure, iis, web-config, azure-web-app-service

I have a ASP.NET Core app hosted as an Azure Web App under a url:

```
https://my-webapp-url.azurewebsites.net/
```

Here is my web config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1048576000" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="aspNetCore" />
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\My.WebApp.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
  </system.webServer>  
</configuration>
```

Any user can access:

- the `https://my-webapp-url.azurewebsites.net/info` page to see the health state of my app
- `https://my-webapp-url.azurewebsites.net/swagger` page to see the API documentation of my app

My problem is the following:

- What needs to be done to allow users to access a hardcoded path like `https://my-webapp-url.azurewebsites.net/my-extra-file.html` such that upon requesting this URL the HTML page would return?

Currently, if i have the `my-extra-file.html` in the `wwwroot` dir of the web app and i try accessing `https://my-webapp-url.azurewebsites.net/my-extra-file.html` i get 404.0.

Thank You in advance and sorry for any mistakes.

Comment: If this is a ASP .NET Core MVC app you need to add `app.UseStaticFiles();` in `Configure` method of the Startup class.

Comment: @Llazar , is it possible to define the configuration for the served `my-extra-file.html` is completely in the `web.config`

Comment: The easy way is to add this method to Startup class because the webserver need this method to serve the statics file like html, css, javascript and image. I am not sure if the configuration can be done from web.config.

Comment: @Llazar , it seems to be the easiest option. Tried editing directly in the config - did not work. Added `app.UseStaticFiles()`, created `wwwroot` folder with necessary files inside in the project - all good. I will post the answer later. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will sum up and post it as an reply.

When you use an Asp.net core mvc app, you need to add `app.UseStaticFiles();` in `Configure` method of the `Startup` class. So that the webserver could server the static file like html, css, javascript and image.

Then create .html file under `wwwroot` folder and you will access to it.